# How to print a concatenation of a string with a list of strings in a loop

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I want to remove all brackets, commands etc. ("[],'")

```
a=3
c=[["A ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a],
["B ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a],
["C ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a]
]
for line in c:
    print(*line, sep="")
```

I want output like this:

```
A |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
B |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
C |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
A ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ']
  ['|———', '|———', '|———']
B ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ']
  ['|———', '|———', '|———']
C ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ']
  ['|———', '|———', '|———']

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I think the below does what you want with the given inputs.

```
for line in c:
    print("".join(["".join(x) for x in line]), sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have three depths of nested lists

Depending your conditions, you can either change the way you generate your table, so that it only has two depths:

```
a=3
c=[["A "] + ["|   "]*a,
["  "] + ["|———"]*a,
["B "] + ["|   "]*a,
["  "] + ["|———"]*a,
["C "] + ["|   "]*a,
["  "] + ["|———"]*a
]
for line in c:
    print(*line, sep="")
```

... or change the way you print it:

```
a=3
c=[["A ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a],
["B ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a],
["C ",["|   "]*a],
["  ",["|———"]*a]
]
for head, line in c:
    print(head, *line, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `"a"*3` is `"aaa"` in python you cana ctually use something like below.

```
a=3
c=[
    ["A ","|   "*a],
    ["  ","|———"*a],
    ["B ","|   "*a],
    ["  ","|———"*a],
    ["C ","|   "*a],
    ["  ","|———"*a]
]
for line in c:
    print(*line, sep="")
```

Output:

```
A |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
B |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
C |   |   |   
  |———|———|———
```